Integration of Dominated continuous function is continuous
Suppose $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $H:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ have the following properties.
1, $H$ is Lebesgue integrable.
2, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $h(x,\cdot):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable
3, $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $h(\cdot,t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous
4, $\forall (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we have $|h(x,t)|\le H(t)$.
Prove that the function $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(x,t)dt \;\;\;\;\;\;\;(Lebesgue\;\,integral)$$
is continuous.
This is in fact a Qualifying problem, I almost have no idea about it. Thank you in advance.

My attempt is to prove it directly by calculating $|\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta\to 0}u(x+\Delta x)-u(x)|=|\lim_{\Delta\to 0}\int_{}h(x+\Delta x,t)dt-\int h(x,t)dt|=|\lim_{\Delta\to 0}\int_{}h(x+\Delta x,t)-h(x,t)dt|$
since $|\lim_{\Delta\to 0}\int_{}h(x+\Delta x,t)-h(x,t)dt|\le\lim_{\Delta\to 0}\int_{}|h(x+\Delta x,t)-h(x,t)|dt\le2\int H(t)dt$, it satisfied Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem.
So we can swap the integral and limit,$|\lim_{\Delta\to 0}\int_{}h(x+\Delta x,t)-h(x,t)dt|$=$|\int_{}\lim_{\Delta\to 0}h(x+\Delta x,t)-h(x,t)dt|$,
since h is continuous, it is proved.
